# How to divide non-multiplicative data frame into as even as possible rows

Tags: r, split

I have a data frame that is 196 rows long, and I would like to divide it into 12 groups (as evenly as possible). I can only do this with 4 groups of 17 rows, and 8 groups of 16 rows.

However, I am only finding one example online that only works for multiplicative data frames:

```
d <- split(dataFrame,rep(1:12,each=16))
```

This would split a 192-row dataFrame into 12 groups of 16 consecutive rows. However, when I try to apply this to a 196-row dataFrame, I get an error:

```
Warning message:
In split.default(x = seq_len(nrow(x)), f = f, drop = drop, ...) :
  data length is not a multiple of split variable
```

I understand the error message, I just don't know to indicate that I would like any remainder to be divided across the groups as evenly as possible.

Comment: Look at `sapply(d, nrow)` and you'll see the distribution of number of rows after the split.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for how to handle the number of groups not dividing the length of the data frame. This is handled well by the `cut` function, operating on the row numbers for each row of your data frame:

```
dat <- data.frame(x=1:196)
spl <- split(dat, cut(seq(nrow(dat)), 12))
str(spl)
# List of 12
#  $ (0.805,17.1]:'data.frame': 17 obs. of  1 variable:
#   ..$ x: int [1:17] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#  $ (17.1,33.4] :'data.frame': 16 obs. of  1 variable:
#   ..$ x: int [1:16] 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 ...
#  $ (33.4,49.7] :'data.frame': 16 obs. of  1 variable:
#   ..$ x: int [1:16] 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 ...
#  $ (49.7,65.9] :'data.frame': 16 obs. of  1 variable:
#   ..$ x: int [1:16] 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 ...
#  $ (65.9,82.2] :'data.frame': 17 obs. of  1 variable:
#   ..$ x: int [1:17] 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 ...
#  $ (82.2,98.5] :'data.frame': 16 obs. of  1 variable:
#   ..$ x: int [1:16] 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 ...
#  $ (98.5,115]  :'data.frame': 16 obs. of  1 variable:
#   ..$ x: int [1:16] 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 ...
#  $ (115,131]   :'data.frame': 17 obs. of  1 variable:
#   ..$ x: int [1:17] 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 ...
#  $ (131,147]   :'data.frame': 16 obs. of  1 variable:
#   ..$ x: int [1:16] 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 ...
#  $ (147,164]   :'data.frame': 16 obs. of  1 variable:
#   ..$ x: int [1:16] 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 ...
#  $ (164,180]   :'data.frame': 16 obs. of  1 variable:
#   ..$ x: int [1:16] 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 ...
#  $ (180,196]   :'data.frame': 17 obs. of  1 variable:
#   ..$ x: int [1:17] 180 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 ...
```

As can be seen from the summary output, four of the groups have 17 observations and the remaining eight groups have 16 observations.